# Why is this SOQL query giving error saying variable does not exist

Tags: apex, soql, compile-error

I am getting error saying variable SBQQ__LineItems__r does not exist when I try to have values saved in the List with below SOQL on CPQ. What could be the issue here:

```
List<SBQQ__Quote__c> qte = [SELECT Id, Name, Installation__c, (SELECT Id, Name, SBQQ__ProductName__c FROM SBQQ__LineItems__r ) FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE Name = 'Q-10427'];

LIST<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> skulist = qte.SBQQ__LineItems__r;
for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c skuname: skulist) {
    System.debug('SKU Name: '+ skuname.SBQQ__ProductName__c);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to reference an attribute `SBQQ__LineItems__r` on a `List<SBQQ__Quote__c>`, but this type does not have that attribute. Rather than referencing the collection, you need to reference a single record within it.

```
List<SBQQ__Quote__c> quotes = [/*query*/];
for (SBQQ__Quote__c quote : quotes)
{
    for (SBQQ_QuoteLine__c lineItem : quote.SBQQ__LineItems__r)
    {
        // now you can manipulate the individual line items
    }
}
```

Notes how we have `SBQQ__Quote__c quote`, so you know the `quote` variable references a *singular* record. Then we know that we can reference `quote.SBQQ__LineItems__r` safely using the child relationship name. Informative naming will often help you avoid confusion in your code. I highly recommend you use complete words and pluralize when using collections, as I have demonstrated above.

Comment: This is great Adrian! Works now. Excellent advice on naming variables. Thank you.